# No implicit view available from fastparse.P[Any] => fastparse.P[Unit]

Tags: scala, fastparse

I am working through the [tutorial/explanation of fastparse](https://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/#Sequence) and am getting the error message

```
error: No implicit view available from fastparse.P[Any] => fastparse.P[Unit]
```

for the [sequence](https://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/#Sequence) example.

I am using sbt 1.3.8 and scala 2.13.1. The defined version for fastparse is 2.2.2.

```
scala> import fastparse._
import fastparse._

scala> def ab[_:P] = P("a" ~ "b")
                           ^
       error: No implicit view available from fastparse.P[Any] => fastparse.P[Unit].

scala> def a[_:P] = P("a")
a: [_](implicit evidence$1: fastparse.P[Any])fastparse.package.P[Unit]

scala> def b[_:P] = P("b")
b: [_](implicit evidence$1: fastparse.P[Any])fastparse.package.P[Unit]

scala> def ab[_:P] = P(a ~ b)
                         ^
       error: No implicit view available from fastparse.package.P[Any] => fastparse.package.P[Unit].

scala> def ab[_:P] = P("a" | "b")
ab: [_](implicit evidence$1: fastparse.P[Any])fastparse.package.P[Unit]

scala> fastparse.parse("a", ab(_))
res2: fastparse.Parsed[Unit] = Parsed.Success((), 1)
```

**What does this error mean and what did I do wrong/how can I conclude this tutorial step without error?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify how to handle [whitespace](https://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/#WhitespaceHandling), for example the following fails

```
import fastparse._
import fastparse.NoWhitespace._

def ab[_:P] = P("a" ~ "b")
assert(parse("a      b", ab(_)).isSuccess)
```

because `"a      b"` contains spaces, whilst the following passes

```
import fastparse._
import fastparse.SingleLineWhitespace._

def ab[_:P] = P("a" ~ "b")
assert(parse("a      b", ab(_)).isSuccess)
```

becase `import fastparse.SingleLineWhitespace._` provides whitespace consumer. If we look at the definition of [`~`](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse/blob/dd74612224846d3743e19419b3f1191554b973f5/fastparse/src/fastparse/package.scala#L142)

```
def ~[V, R](other:  P[V])
           (implicit s: Implicits.Sequencer[T, V, R],
            whitespace: P[Any] => P[Unit],
            ctx: P[_]): P[R] = macro MacroImpls.parsedSequence[T, V, R]
```

we see `implicit whitespace: P[Any] => P[Unit]` requirement which explains `No implicit view available` error. The whitespace imports provide this capability, for example

```
object NoWhitespace {
  implicit object noWhitespaceImplicit extends (ParsingRun[_] => ParsingRun[Unit]){
    def apply(ctx: ParsingRun[_]) = ctx.freshSuccessUnit()
  }
}
```

where we see `ParsingRun[_] => ParsingRun[Unit]` implicit function.

Answer (score 2):

You missed one more import

```
import NoWhitespace._
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qCKZEnRHS7eOhjpVjtWNIQ